# What is the black finish on my woodburning stove

Tags: woodstove

My antique stove has a black finish. It’s usually polished with grate polish. Some rust has developed. If I remove the rust back to a (relatively) smooth surface I expose the shiny metal. I’m unsure what the black finish is and how to get it back. It’s made of cast iron with a sheet metal firebrick-lined “cylinder”.

Is the finish on the sheet metal likely to be black oxide or does it just come from the grate polish? If it’s black oxide, could I let it rust very slightly and apply a rust converter to blacken it?

[image: Rusty stove]

Comment: As an antique, it's probably **stove black** *aka* **stove polish.** Newer stoves may use a high temperature paint. If it gets hot enough but not too hot (hard to know) linseed oil will give iron a black, rustproof finish (common for blacksmith-made items.) But it will burn off if it's too hot, and not set in a reasonable time (nor turn black) if it's not hot enough.

Answer (score 1):

I can remember cleaning our big Franco-belge stove with wire wool and then 2 coats of Zeebrite black stove polish which would last about a month as it was the cooking surface.